# PrestaShop: Split customized data from the product row in the cart summary

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

There is a way to show customized data of the same product (with certain ID) separated into several rows for each uploaded file? Actually (in the newest version of this software  1.6.1.1 ) 2 products with different customized data fields are in 1 row. I want to have them separated by 2 rows and shown as different products.

[image]

Comment: It's not easy. PrestaShop manage the customization files as 'one customization', so you have to make a 'big' override to change single uploaded file as a one customization. Tip: start from `_addCustomization()` method of `Cart` class

Comment: You can loopt through the customizations and display the products within them. But then if there is no customization for one product, you would have to write and exception for that. I tried, it's not easy.